# First film roll just got developed and all my pictures have a white fog on them?

Tags: film, 35mm, developing, fujifilm, film-cameras

I recently got an olympus om10 and shot my first roll of film,
The film  is fujicolour c200.

I got my film developed and when I picked it up, the guy in the shop said some of them were really dark. The pictures have come out kinda blurry and with this weird white fog on the bottom of them (*pictures below*)

[image]
[image]

and one came out with different colour lines like this:

[image]

Why is this and how do I prevent it from happening?

I'm also missing some photos and when I was shooting the camera advance lever stopped advancing, I didn't know if it got jammed because i definitely still had some shots left but the counter said S?

Another thing, i put the film in the fridge after i had used it, took it out to warm to room temp but because no shops were developing i had to put it back in the fridge. Would this have affected the film and caused the fog?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you understand about metering? What settings were you using and how did you choose them?

Comment: @bea cav - Have you used film much before, or are you used to digital photography? There are so many possible ways to get a light leak into the body and on to the film during loading the film, using the camera, or taking the film out. Did you load / unload quickly, somewhere dark, and put the film in the canister immediately? Also if your camera creaks (try to squeeze it) that might indicate the back is a bit loose, which could give you a leak too.

Comment: the challenges in the last image are a mix of light leak and metering. The subject is in front of a light background, which is a difficult shot to light well - either the subject will be too dark and the background visible, or the subject will be visible and the background will be overexposed.

Comment: I know you don't desire this "effect", but it makes for some very interesting photographs.

Answer (score 15):

The orange veil to the right of the last image is a common effect of light fogging.  In fact, I've seen that many times on the first frame of 35mm when I started exposing without winding enough frames first.

The white fog might be a different sort of light leak, perhaps due to the shutter not being completely closed when you advance film and cock the camera.s  The very dark frames might be due to a metering problem, or could be operator error.  Overall, however, I think it's pretty safe to say that your camera needs service.

Comment: It would be easier to tell if we could see the negatives, including the rebate (the edges with the perforations), and without converting them back to positive.  Darkroom workers are more used to evaluating negatives directly than to evaluating scans of them, and the fogging on the rebate will give additional information as to the cause.  (e.g. shutter faults can't fog the rebate.)

Comment: @JimMacKenzie I agree with you, but I've owned an SLR that had the problem I describe -- shutter not fully capping, leaving a bright (in the positive) streak along the top of the images.  These are at the bottom, which might indicate a slow second curtain -- if there's no such fogging between frames, that's more likely than open while advancing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but did your camera go through an airport scanner? [Certain scanners can damage unprocessed film,](https://www.kodak.com/global/en/service/tib/tib5201.shtml) it is therefore recommended to remove the film from the camera before you get to security and get it hand-checked if possible

Comment: Good point, but scanners usually equally expose the film so you get uniform fogging (not over exposure as here). This is light creeping in from one side, unfortunately.

Comment: Some of the examples I have seen show fogging on one side only, e.g. https://digitalrev.com/2015/10/25/travel-horror-what-happened-when-my-film-was-x-ray-scanned-11-times/  . There are different types of scanner that have different effects. However, I agree that in this particular case it looks more like a problem with the camera itself

Comment: Airport scanners will fog film, but not to this degree- and it takes a couple of doses to really measure it. As an experiment I did so- fresh Tmax 3200, exposed and unexposed, and traveled with. There as a measurable base fog lift using calibrated instruments in a professional lab but nothing that would have been responsible for the above.